raise ValueError( ValueError: Cannot assign "'TJFIDEL2401'": "Order.discount_code" must be a "DiscountCode" instance
I'm trying to implement a checkout page using Django framework. I have DiscountCode model linked to the Order model as discount_code = models.ForeignKey(DiscountCode, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True). When I proceed to click on the place order button on the checkout page, an error message occurs that is, raise ValueError(ValueError: Cannot assign "''": "Order.discount_code" must be a "DiscountCode" instance. - I have spent already a couple of hours trying to resolve this issue.
The problem occurs when the form.is_valid() is triggered
Models:
class DiscountCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)  # Unique discount code
    # e.g., 10.00 for a fixed amount discount
    discount_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    # e.g., 10.00% for percentage discount
    discount_percent = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField()
    valid_until = models.DateTimeField()
    # Number of times the discount can be used
    max_uses = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    # Assign to specific users or leave empty for all users
    users = models.ManyToManyField(Account, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # Active status

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

    def is_valid(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return self.is_active and self.valid_from <= now <= self.valid_until and self.max_uses > 0


class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('New', 'New'),
        ('Processing', 'Processing'),
        ('Shipped', 'Shipped'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    payment = models.ForeignKey(
        Payment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    discount_code = models.ForeignKey(
        DiscountCode, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)


Please add the associated views.py and the html template.

It happens because Django expects you to assign an actual instance of the DiscountCode model to the discount_code field of the Order model, but you are assigning a string.
What would fix this:-
discount_code_instance = DiscountCode.objects.get(code='tjfidel2401')
order.discount_code = discount_code_instance
order.save()


Thanks! That was the solution.
